# How to sum 3d Matrix row by interval in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `36x256x2232` 3d matrix in Matlab created by `M = ones(36,256,2232)` and I want to reduce the size of the matrix by sum rows by interval 3. The result matrix should be `12x256x2232` and each cell should have the value 3.

I tried using `reshape` and `sum` function but I get 1x256x2232 matrix.

How can I do this without using the `for-loop` ?

Comment: If you reshape into a 4th dimension (of length 3) then `sum` will work fine. If your actual implementation doesn't have constant values then making sure the correct values are in the right places may be trickier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
M = ones(36,256,2232)
reduced = reshape(sum(reshape(M, 3,[], 256,2232), 1),[], 256, 2232);
```

- `reshape` makes a 4d matrix with the given intervals
- `sum` reduce it
- second reshape transform it to 3d again

you can use also `squeeze`, which removes singleton dimensions:

```
reduced = squeeze(sum(reshape(M, 3,[], 256,2232), 1));
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I've finally got the 4d matrix. But now, how can I pass from reduced matrix to  12-256-2232 3d matrix ?

Comment: Found the solution: using `squeeze(reduced)` I obtain the result! Thanks.

Comment: if it aswers you question, please consider accepting!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new-ish [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) function (which is similar to `accumarray` but can handle data with multiple dimensions). This approach works even if the number of rows is not a multiple of the group size:

```
M = ones(4,5,2); % example data
n = 3; % group size
result = splitapply(@(x)sum(x,1), M, floor((0:size(M,1)-1).'/n)+1);
```